# Python numpy.ndarray compare

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, compare

How can I compare array elements in a `numpy.ndarray`?

My `ndarray` is like this

```
array([[ 781,   94],
       [ 781,  656],
       [1367,   94],
       [1367,  656]])
```

Required Output:

```
array([781, 94, 656, 1367])
```

Comment: Could you update your post to reflect what you mean by "compare"? How do you get that required output from your array?

Comment: @OliverW. I didn't get it yet. I want output based on common elements in individual arrays.

Comment: Still not a clear description of the problem at hand. You took an array that has 8 elements, of which only 4 are unique. Please explain, *in your post* **in words** how you obtain that output array from your initial array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want unique values in your array

```
In [16]: arr = np.array([[ 781,   94],
       [ 781,  656],
       [1367,   94],
       [1367,  656]])

In [17]: np.unique(arr)
Out[17]: array([  94,  656,  781, 1367])
```

Comment: Yes I wanted unique elements out of my array. Thanks :)